# JSFL: selecting items returned by fl.findObjectInDocByType()

Tags: jsfl

I can't seem to use the info returned by `fl.findObjectInDocByType()` with `fl.getDocumentDOM().selection`.

I want to use `document.setTextRectangle` to re-size some text fields from an array generated using `fl.findObjectInDocByType()`.

I can easily access all the textObject properties but since `document.setTextRectangle` requires a current selection, I am at a loss.

The example in the documentaion for setting selection is:

```
fl.getDocumentDOM().selection = fl.getDocumentDOM().getTimeline().layers[0].frames[0].elements[0];
```

`fl.findObjectInDocByType()` returns an array of objects with the attributes: (`object.timeline`, `object.layer`, `object.frame`, `object.parent`)

But these are objects, and don't have a property for array index numbers required by `fl.getDocumentDOM().selection=`...

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var textFieldArray = fl.findObjectInDocByType("text", doc);
    for (var i=0; i < textFieldArray.length; i ++){
        fnResizeTheTextField(textFieldArray[i]);
    }

function fnResizeTheTextField(theTextField){
        //force current selection to be theTextField
        //doc.selection MUST be an array, so assign theTextField to an array...
        var selectArray = new Array();
        selectArray[0] = theTextField.obj;
        var theTimeline =theTextField.timeline;
        var theLayer =theTextField.layer;
        var theFrame =theTextField.frame;
        doc.currentTimeline =theTextField.timeline;
        doc.selection = doc.getTimeline().theLayer.theFrame.selectArray;//error
        //resize the text rectangle
        doc.setTextRectangle({left:0, top:0, right:1000, bottom:1000});
    }
}
```

Result: `Error:doc.getTimeline().theLayer has no properties`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, the ObjectFindAndSelect.jsfl script already contains a function specifically for this: fl.selectElement(). Much more elegant:

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
// generate an array of elements of type "text"
var textFieldArray = fl.findObjectInDocByType("text", doc);
    for (var i=0; i < textFieldArray.length; i ++){
        fnResizeTheTextField(textFieldArray[i]);
    }

function fnResizeTheTextField(theTextField){
        //force current selection to be theTextField
        fl.selectElement(theTextField,false);//enter 'edit mode' =false...
        //resize the text rectangle
        doc.setTextRectangle({left:0, top:0, right:1000, bottom:1000});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In order to select anything for a document level operation, you have to also make flash focus on the **keyframe** of that object.

so, if I loop through an array of objects created by  fl.findObjectInDocByType(), I use this code to make flash focus on the object correctly:

```
function fnMakeFlashLookAt(theObject){
        doc.currentTimeline =theObject.timeline;
        doc.getTimeline().currentLayer =theObject.layer;
        doc.getTimeline().currentFrame =theObject.frame;
    }
```

this may not work on objects nested inside a symbol however.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, and apparently all google results about `setTextRectangle()` direct us here. It's unbelievable how poorly documented jsfl is :)

If you need to use `setTextRectangle()` inside an library item that is not on stage, you need to open for edit the item first.

Here's the code that solved my problem:

```
library.selectItem(libraryItemName);
doc.selection = [tf];//where tf is the reference to textfield we need to edit
doc.library.editItem(libraryItemName);  
doc.setTextRectangle({left:l, top:t, right:r, bottom:b});
doc.selectNone();
```

If you have a better working solution, please post. I hope it saves somebody's time. Good luck!